# Undefined index: userid

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating an edit user profile for my project. I came across this error "
Notice: Undefined index: userid in C:\xampp\htdocs\HelloWorld\EditProfile.php on line 18
". I've spent an hour trying to find the cause of the error but I can't seem to find it. I followed this guide here [php -'Edit' function for forum posts and such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342258/edit-function-for-forum-posts-and-such) Here's my code:

**EditProfile.php**

```
<?php 
// connect to SQL
$dbcnx = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "2345fypj");
if (!$dbcnx)
  {
  echo( "<P>Unable to connect to the database server at this time.</P>" );
  exit();
}

// connect to database
$dbcon = mysql_select_db("my_db", $dbcnx);
if (!$dbcon) {
  echo( "<P>Unable to locate DB table at this time.</P>" );
  exit();
}

//data preparation for the query
$id = intval($_GET['userid']);

// selects title and description fields from database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE userid=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());        
# retrieved by using $row['col_name']
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>

<h3>Edit</h3>
<form action="save_edit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="myForm" />
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Name</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="70" maxlength="100" name="title" value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Age</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="70" maxlength="100" name="title" value="<?php echo $row['age'] ?>"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
  <input name="enter" type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>

<?php 
mysql_close($dbcnx);
?>
```

**save_edit.php**

```
<?php
// connect to SQL
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "2345fypj");
if (!$con) {
  echo( "<P>Unable to connect to the database server at this time.</P>" );
  exit();
}
// connect to database
$dbcon = @mysql_select_db("user_profile", $con);
if (!$dbcon) {
  echo( "<P>Unable to locate DB table at this time.</P>" );
  exit();
}

#data preparation for the query
$id = intval($_POST["userid"]);
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);

$sql = "UPDATE user_profile SET 
        name='$_POST[name]', 
        age='$_POST[age]', 
        WHERE userid=$id";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($con);
header ("location: http://www.domain.com/url_to_go_to_after_update");
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read similar questions in the right part of this page. PS: blind copy-paste without understanding what code does never results in something good

Comment: "EditProfile.php on line 18", what is the content of line 18?

Comment: @icktoofay it was more to "think what you have in line 18, the error is there" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to use variable `$_GET['userid']` while it's undefined. This variable refers to GET parameter in URL (e.g. `EditProfile.php?userid=42`). If this parameter isn't passed in URL, you will get this warning. You should check existence of variable:

```
if (!isset($_GET['userid'])) {
  die("Parameter is missing!");  
}

$id = intval($_GET['userid']);
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that I have to add 'userid=3' to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = intval($_GET['userid']);
```

It means set the `$id` variable to the "userid" variable in your URL. For example, if your URL is mySite.com?userid=12, $id will be set to "12". if your URL doesn't have "username=aValue" at the end section of it, you'll get the error you're seeing. :)

You could change it to this to set a default value:

```
$id = (isset($_GET['userid']) ? intval($_GET['userid']) : -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be sure that the value is correctly set before trying to access it. Try using the isset function beforehand.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is apart from using a variable before its used, your continuing todo the query when setting to a default value with intval (will always return atleast 0), which if a non numeric character is passed your always going to update the row 0 user in the table, what you should be doing is not updating anything and returning the user with an error. You also have a rouge `,` after you `age` column in the query.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["userid"]) && is_numeric($_POST["userid"])){

    $_POST = array_walk($_POST,'mysql_real_escape_string');

    $sql = "UPDATE `user_profile` SET `name`='{$_POST['name']}', `age`='{$_POST['age']}' 
            WHERE `userid` = {$_POST['userid']}";
    mysql_query($sql);

}else{
    header('Location: ./failed');
}
?>
```